# playwright page.getByLabel() resolved to 2 elements

Tags: typescript, playwright, playwright-typescript

I am learning playwright and i find page.getByLabel is very usefulm but i try to find input elements i think finds the same twice.

```
> test('Fill Contact details and verify should success', async ({ page }) => {
          await page.goto('https://practice.automationbro.com/contact/')
          
          const inputName = page.getByLabel('Name')
          const inputEmail = page.getByLabel('Email')
          const inputPhone = page.getByLabel('Phone')
          const inputMessage = page.getByLabel('Message')
          const buttonSubmit = page.getByRole('button', {name : 'Submit'})

          await inputName.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()
          await inputName.fill('Name')

          await inputEmail.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()
          await inputEmail.fill('Email@name.com')

          await inputPhone.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();
          await inputPhone.fill('+36123456789')    
          
          await inputMessage.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()
          await inputMessage.fill('Lorem Ipsum')
          
          await buttonSubmit.click()

          await expect(page.getByText('Thanks for contacting us! We will be in touch with you shortly')).toBeVisible();
     })
```

When i run it fails with :

```
1) [chromium] › automationbro.spec.ts:75:10 › Home › Fill Contact details and verify should success 

    locator.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded: Error: strict mode violation: getByLabel('Message') resolved to 2 elements:
        1) <textarea class="input-text" id="evf-277-field_yhGx3FOwr2-…></textarea> aka getByRole('textbox', { name: 'Message' })
        2) <input type="text" class="input-text" id="evf-277-field…/> aka locator('#evf-277-field-hp')

    =========================== logs ===========================
    waiting for getByLabel('Message')
    ============================================================

      91 |           await inputPhone.fill('+36123456789')    
      92 |           
    > 93 |           await inputMessage.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()
         |                              ^
      94 |           await inputMessage.fill('Lorem Ipsum')
      95 |           
      96 |           await buttonSubmit.click()
```

Page has only one input element with that label. Why did it find 2 elements?

Comment: Can you share some HTML?

Comment: https://practice.automationbro.com/contact/
Live practise site, you can check the html online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the labels are linked to hidden as well as visible input fields. One way to disambiguate is with `getByRole`:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.30.0

test("fill contact details and verify", async ({page}) => {
  await page.goto("https://practice.automationbro.com/contact/");

  const inputName = page.getByRole("textbox", {name: "Name"});
  const inputEmail = page.getByRole("textbox", {name: "Email"});
  const inputPhone = page.getByRole("textbox", {name: "Phone"});
  const inputMessage = page.getByRole("textbox", {name: "Message"});
  const buttonSubmit = page.getByRole("button", {name: "Submit"});

  await inputName.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();
  await inputName.fill("Name");

  await inputEmail.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();
  await inputEmail.fill("Email@name.com");

  await inputPhone.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();
  await inputPhone.fill("+36123456789");

  await inputMessage.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();
  await inputMessage.fill("Lorem Ipsum");

  await buttonSubmit.click();

  await expect(
    page.getByText(
      "Thanks for contacting us! We will be in touch with you shortly"
    )
  ).toBeVisible();
});
```

That said, I don't think you need to `scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()`. I'd remove the variables and use something like

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test";

test("fill contact details and verify", async ({page}) => {
  await page.goto("https://practice.automationbro.com/contact/");
  await page.getByRole("textbox", {name: "Name"}).fill("Name");
  await page.getByRole("textbox", {name: "Email"}).fill("Email@name.com");
  await page.getByRole("textbox", {name: "Phone"}).fill("+36123456789");
  await page.getByRole("textbox", {name: "Message"}).fill("Lorem Ipsum");
  await page.getByRole("button", {name: "Submit"}).click();
  await expect(
    page.getByText(
      "Thanks for contacting us! We will be in touch with you shortly"
    )
  ).toBeVisible();
});
```

Comment: It is working. Thank you!
Did not know about getByRole() has a name option which is working on label texts. 

The funny part is my version with the getByLabel() sometime passes and sometime fails.

Comment: Those hidden elements seem to be created asynchronously creating a race condition.

Comment: Yehh you were right .... honeypot hidden input elements generated randomly.  
I think it is a kinda form protection. But seems to me it can be avoided  very easily.

Comment: Clarification: based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75778903/6243352) they're not generated async and there's no race condition; one field is randomly selected server-side and set into static HTML, making it feel like a race condition.

Answer (score 2):

And an other one. This is the first time I've seen honeypot protection on forms.

Nice try :D

So the page randomly generates one honeypot hidden input which one is similar to one of the visibles. This is why my version randomly breaks.

```css
.evf-honeypot-container {
    display: none!important;
    position: absolute!important;
    left: -9000px!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="evf-honeypot-container evf-field-hp">
  <label for="evf-277-field-hp" class="evf-field-label">Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="everest_forms[hp]" id="evf-277-field-hp" class="input-text">
</div>
```

So the question is why `getByRole()` is working and `getByLabel()` is not.

The answer is in the playwright documentation.
`getByRole()` is more sophisticated and has much more options than `getByLabel()`.

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-get-by-role
[...]

includeHidden boolean (optional)#

Option that controls whether hidden elements are matched. By default, only non-hidden elements, as defined by ARIA, are matched by role selector.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find out the problem html looks like this :

```html
<div id="evf-277-field_LbH5NxasXM-2-container" class="evf-field evf-field-email form-row contact-email validate-required validate-email" data-required-field-message="Please enter a valid email address." data-field-id="LbH5NxasXM-2">
  <label class="evf-field-label" for="evf-277-field_LbH5NxasXM-2">
    <span class="evf-label">Email</span> 
    <abbr class="required" title="Required">*</abbr>
</label><input type="email" id="evf-277-field_LbH5NxasXM-2" class="input-text" name="everest_forms[form_fields][LbH5NxasXM-2]" required=""></div>
```

"label" has two sub elements span and abbr and the full label text is 'Email *'

So the correct getByLabel selector is

```js
await page.getByLabel('Email *').fill('Email@name.com')
```

OR

```js
await page.getByLabel('Email *', {exact: true}).fill('Email@name.com')
```

Comment: Great point. However, I was seeing some failures with `Message` too, but since it doesn't have a `*` required field to disambiguate the text, I'm not sure if this generalizes fully. Also, if a field suddenly loses its required `*` in the future it'd probably cause a failure.

Answer (score -1):

yes,
because when you are preforming action on the page,
the Dom also change, so the elements you located, are now different...

the Best way, is to find element just before you doing action:

```js
test('Fill Contact details and verify should success', async ({ page }) => {
          await page.goto('https://practice.automationbro.com/contact/')

          const inputName = page.getByLabel('Name')
          await inputName.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()
          await inputName.fill('Name')

          const inputEmail = page.getByLabel('Email')
          await inputEmail.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()
          await inputEmail.fill('Email@name.com')

          const inputPhone = page.getByLabel('Phone')
          await inputPhone.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();
          await inputPhone.fill('+36123456789')    
 
          const inputMessage = page.getByLabel('Message')
          await inputMessage.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()
          await inputMessage.fill('Lorem Ipsum')
          
          const buttonSubmit = page.getByRole('button', {name : 'Submit'})
          await buttonSubmit.click()

          await expect(page.getByText('Thanks for contacting us! We will be in touch with you shortly')).toBeVisible();
     })
```

Comment: This seems to fail for me as OP's code does.